# Automate Internet Explorer: enter a value that has no "ID"

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use excel VBA to automate the data entering on a intranet Webpage of my company.  I know how to interact with values of a web page the fields have "id"  like in the html code below

```
<input name="txtUserName" tabindex="1" id="txtUserName" type="text">
```

With that kind of html code I would use something like

```
IE.Document.getElementbyId("txtUserName").Value = "UserName"
```

The problem I'm facing is that the code associated with the field I'm trying to interact is

```
        <HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            function ajusterFrames() {
                var iLargeurGauche = 217;
                var iLargeurDroite = 850;
                var iLargeurFenetre = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
                var iMarge = 0;
                var sCols = "";
                if (iLargeurFenetre > (iLargeurGauche + iLargeurDroite)) {
                    iMarge = (iLargeurFenetre - (iLargeurGauche + iLargeurDroite)) / 2;}
                sCols = (iLargeurGauche + iMarge) + ",*";
                document.getElementById("framesetbas").cols = sCols;
                document.getElementById("cadres").style.display = "block";}
            window.onload = ajusterFrames;
            window.onresize = ajusterFrames;
        </SCRIPT>
```

```
                            <TBODY>
                                <TR> </TR>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD>
                                        <!--RECHERCHE-->
                                            DIV id=Projet>
                                            <!--RECHERCHE-->
                                                <CENTER>
                                                    <FIELDSET style="WIDTH: 600px" name="recherche">
                                                    <LEGEND style="FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; COLOR: #767676" name="legende_recherche">
                                                    <INPUT onclick=afficherRecherche(this.value); type=radio value=simple name=TypeRecherche>
                                                    </DIV><!------RECHERCHE AVANCÉE------------------------------------->
                                                    <DIV id=divAvancee>
                                                        <CENTER>
                                                            <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
                                                                <TBODY>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TR>
                                                                    <TD align=right>
                                                                        <FONT color=#003366 size=1 face=verdana>No Projet :</FONT></TD>
```

So I'm trying to modify the value of the field identify by:  "txtNoProjet"   Here's the code I could come up with, I tried many versions around this and still can't get it right.
UPDATED CODE TO INCLUDE SOLUTION

```
Private Sub entree_budget()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim buttonCollection As Object
Dim valeur_heure As Object

num_proj = Cells(1, 3)              'this is the value that I need to input

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "http://intranet.cima.ca/fr/application/paq/projets/index.asp?v1_lang=1"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

'UPDATED CODE BELOW

```
    Set links = IE.Document.frames(2).Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
         n = links.Length   
    While i < n
            If links(i).Name = "txtMotCle" Then        
                links(i).Value = num_proj
            End If  
  i = i+ 1  
Wend 

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this?
And also if I may I will the need to click the button "search" on the bottom of the form , but I can't recognize it's syntax so I don't know how to interact with it.  Could someone tell me how to click the button that has this html code?

```
<A href="javascript:submitForm('avancee');">
<IMG border=0 alt="Rechercher un projet" src="../../../images/fr/rechercher.gif"></A>
```

UPDATED CODE  SOLUTION FOR THIS IS:

```
Set links = IE.Document.frames(2).Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
 n = links.LengtH
i = 0
While i < n
    If links(i).href = "javascript:submitForm('avancee');" Then           
        Set objElement = links(i)
        objElement.ClicK
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Thank you so much in advance for the time you'll spend answering my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited: the input elements were contained in a frame, which is why @jeeped's answer wasn't working.  getElementsByTagName("input") should have returned them.  Hopefully this edit will save you from having to read through the comments to find that out.  To return inputs contained in a frame, use**

```
IE.document.frames(x).document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

**where x is the index of the frame.**

Original response below.

=======================================================

If it's zero-based, shouldn't you remove the -1 that's preventing the loop from running?  That is, if there is one element, then the for loop would be `iNPT = 0 to 0` and execute once.  If there were two, then the `.length` would return 1 and `=0 to 1` would execute twice, as expected.

I personally would probably include both Microsoft Internet Controls and  Microsoft HTML Object Library in the references for the project so that I could use early binding and declare the variables, and then use a for each to iterate:

```
Dim inputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim inpt As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://intranet.cima.ca/fr/application/paq/projets/index.asp?v1_lang=1"
While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

Set inputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each inpt In inputs
    If inpt.Name = "txtNoProjet" Then inpt.Value = num_proj
    Next
```

Be aware that the HTML Object Library includes several different IHTMLElementCollections, with different numbers.  In some situations you might need to use one of those instead.  Also, you may need to use `getAttribute` to access the attribute:

```
If inpt.getAttribute("name") = "txtNoProjet" then inpt.Value = num_proj
```

Comment: Tx for the try.  But still no luck!  The for loop is just ignored.  The "inputs" variable is empty.  Second option "If  inpt.getAttribute..."  gives me a run time error 91.  This one's a tricky one obviously.  Any other possibilities?

Comment: It is a  *zero-based index* and a *conventionally numbered length*. They are not the same thing. If there are three `<input>` elements then `.getElementsbyTagName("input").length` returns **3**. They are accessed as `.getElementsbyTagName("input")(0)`, `.getElementsbyTagName("input")(1)` and `.getElementsbyTagName("input")(2)`.

Comment: @ jeeped could you look at my updated html code and comment on @tricky suggestion.   Basically length returns 0 for value.  IT seems that we're not using the appropriate syntax to call it.  Any other taughts on this

Comment: Ah, sorry, @jeeped, didn't realize.  getElementsByTagName() should be  returning all the input elements.  @excelguigui11, yes, the page source would help.  Is there any chance of getting the entire page source, instead of a snippet?  I copied what you have to a text document (starting with <TBODY> and ending with </FONT>) as is and loaded using a `buffer` variable:

    Dim doc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    doc.write(buffer)    

and it works as expected. Why don't you try

`test = IE.document.body.outerHTML

and see what you actually have for the source.

Comment: @TrickySam  Not sure I understand what you want me to do.  The returned value of test is :    `frameBorder=0 name=gauche marginWidth=0 scrolling=no leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"><FRAME marginHeight=0 src="./recherche.asp?txtNoProjet=" name=contenu marginWidth=0 leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"></FRAMESET></FRAMESET>`

Comment: That's why you're not getting any input elements.  They're all in the frame, and that source isn't automatically returned back to the top document for you to manipulate.  Assuming that that is the only frame on the page, then you would do this:

`IE.document.frames(0).document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

to get the frame source.  You might have to do 

   `IE.document.frames(0).document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: @TrickySam.  Thank you so much!.  I'll update my code soon with the right code when I'll have it complete.   Would you be kind enough to look at the second part of my question.    I have a button on the page that I need to click on.    Code is:  `A href="javascript:submitForm('avancee');">
<IMG border=0 alt="Rechercher un projet" src="../../../images/fr/rechercher.gif"></A>  `   Could you show me how to click that button?

Comment: Is that href unique to it?  If so, you could create an element collection of tags named "a" to get the collection of anchor tags (`MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement`) and then you would iterate them and match the href.  However, I think that you can just submit that form without having to click the button, unless the page has some kind of event validation.

I think you can do something like `.document.forms("avancee").submit` but you might have to know the index of the form to do it that way. If so, iterate over the forms (`MSHTML.IHTMLFormElement`) and then click the one named avancee.

Answer (score 0):

The index to a collection of elements is *zero-based*. Assuming that there is only a single `txtNoProjet` you would use,

```
IE.Document.getElementsbyName("txtNoProjet")(0).Value = num_proj
```

I've had trouble with `.getElementsbyName` in the past. If the above does not work for you, collect all of the `<input>` elements and cycle through them until you find the one you want.

```
dim iNPT as long
for iNPT=0 to (IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("input").length - 1)
  if IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("input")(iNPT).name = "txtNoProjet" then
    IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("input")(iNPT).value = num_proj
    exit for
  end if
next iNPT
```

One of those should get you going. The biggest problem you will run into would be duplicate names.

**EDIT:** addendum for clicking an image anchor

```
dim iIMG as long
for iIMG=0 to (IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("img").length - 1)
  if CBool(InStr(1, IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("img")(iIMG).src, "rechercher.gif", vbTextCompare)) then
    IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("img")(iIMG).click
    do while IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Do Events: Loop
    exit for
  end if
next iIMG
```

I usually prefer something closer to `IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("form")(0).submit` but you haven't provided enough HTML source code to write that properly. You *will* have to adjust that code to look into your `.Frames` element.

Comment: Tx for your help, but it doesn't work.  First one returns a  run time error 91  Run Time Error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.  The second one does nothing because the getElementsbyTagName("input").length  returns a 0 value.  Any other taughts on this?

Comment: @excelguigui11 this ereror you describe happens typically because the page has not finished loading, you may have issue with your waiting loop. `Application.Wait` is often not reliable. You could try `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend` instead.

Comment: @DavidZemens  Tx for the insight  but I ran the code line by line but still get the same result.  Any other possibilities someone could share

Comment: Sorry, my comment was too long, as new answer below.

Comment: @ Jeeped and @ David Zemens, I updated the html code, could you take another look at my problem please

Comment: @excelguigui11 - please see my edit that addresses your second concern. The sample will have to be adjusted to work within your frames.