# Excel VBA - XMLHTTP: How to refer to button with no ID, only name

Tags: html, vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, getelementbyid

I have been attempting to log in to a website using Excel VBA

The user name and password fields work fine

It's the button to click that's giving me issues

The button does not have an 'ID' rather a name

See Image: [image]

See highlighted line

```
Dim siteDoc As Object
Set siteDoc = appIE.document

   siteDoc.getElementById("xName").Value = "user"
   siteDoc.getElementById("xPassword").Value = "password"
   siteDoc.getElementById("loginbutton").Click
```

I receive my Run-time 424 Object Required error on: `siteDoc.getElementById("loginbutton").Click`

Edit:
In the inspect element 'Console' it returns a `node list`

Edit:

What worked:

```
Set buttonObject = siteDoc.getElementsByName("loginbutton")
For Each btnObj In buttonObject
    btnObj.Click
Next btnObj
```

Comment: Iterate the collection returned by `.getElementsByTagName("button")` and check the `name` attribute. This question has been asked tons of times. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375118/automate-internet-explorer-enter-a-value-that-has-no-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate Internet Explorer: enter a value that has no "ID"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375118/automate-internet-explorer-enter-a-value-that-has-no-id)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the collection of buttons (class names "button") and loop through until you get the name attribute "loginbutton"

1. Assign IHTMLElementCollection (`Set Buttons= doc.getElementsByClassName("button")`)
2. Loop through `Buttons` object to find the login button - your whole code would look like this:

   Sub Example()

   Set Buttons = doc.getElementsByClassName("button")

   For Each oElement In Buttons
       If oElement.getAttribute("name") = "loginbutton" Then
           ' this oElement is you button so you action goes below here
           '........
       End If
   Next

   End Sub

Declare `oElement` and `Buttons` as objects

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to change the format to show my code as code!